# Lock or unlock a directory and its content recursively

Tags: clearcase

Using ClearCase, how can I lock (or unlock) a directory and its complete content recursively?

(It seems to me that neither the GUI nor `cleartool` supports recursive (un)locking, so probably I would have to write a batch file recursing over all the content of a directory. Maybe I overlooked something?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it does not seem possible to use [`cleartool unlock`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_7.1.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_unlock.htm) recursively, one solution could be to combine it to a [`cleartool find`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_7.1.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_unlock.htm) command:

```
# Windows syntax:
cleartool find adirectory -exec "cleartool unlock \"%CLEARCASE_PN%\""
# Unix syntax:
cleartool find adirectory -exec 'cleartool unlock "$CLEARCASE_PN"'
```

If you execute it in the path where `adirectory` is to be unlocked, it will do so for `adirectory` and all its content.

Comment: For the sake of completeness: %CLEARCASE_PN% is “Path name of selected element or VOB symbolic link”.

Comment: @Martin indeed. I suppose here it is preferable to `CLEARCASE_XPN`, which would select the version.